# How to get a random virtual number keyboard

Tags: java, android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxyGT.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lP9xu.jpg)

I want a numeric keypad that changes the number postion everytime i open the app
I have done the Numbers to and it working but i want to shuffle like the iamges i attached above

How to achieve it?

MyKeyboard.java

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputConnection;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MyKeyboard extends LinearLayout implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button button1, button2, button3, button4,
            button5, button6, button7, button8,
            button9, button0, buttonDelete, buttonEnter;

    private SparseArray<String> keyValues = new SparseArray<>();
    private InputConnection inputConnection;

    public MyKeyboard(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public MyKeyboard(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public MyKeyboard(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.keyboard, this, true);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_3);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);
        button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_4);
        button4.setOnClickListener(this);
        button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_5);
        button5.setOnClickListener(this);
        button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_6);
        button6.setOnClickListener(this);
        button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_7);
        button7.setOnClickListener(this);
        button8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_8);
        button8.setOnClickListener(this);
        button9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_9);
        button9.setOnClickListener(this);
        button0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_0);
        button0.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_delete);
        buttonDelete.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonEnter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_enter);
        buttonEnter.setOnClickListener(this);

        keyValues.put(R.id.button_1, "1");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_2, "2");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_3, "3");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_4, "4");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_5, "5");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_6, "6");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_7, "7");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_8, "8");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_9, "9");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_0, "0");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_enter, "\n");
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (inputConnection == null)
            return;

        if (view.getId() == R.id.button_delete) {
            CharSequence selectedText = inputConnection.getSelectedText(0);

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(selectedText)) {
                inputConnection.deleteSurroundingText(1, 0);
            } else {
                inputConnection.commitText("", 1);
            }
        } else {
            String value = keyValues.get(view.getId());
            inputConnection.commitText(value, 1);
        }
    }

    public void setInputConnection(InputConnection ic) {
        inputConnection = ic;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.myapplication;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputConnection;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            MyKeyboard keyboard = (MyKeyboard) findViewById(R.id.keyboard);
            editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            editText.setTextIsSelectable(true);

            InputConnection ic = editText.onCreateInputConnection(new EditorInfo());
            keyboard.setInputConnection(ic);
        }
    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#c9c9f1"
        android:layout_margin="50dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />

    <com.example.myapplication.MyKeyboard
        android:id="@+id/keyboard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

keyboard.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:text="2"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="3"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="4"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="5"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="6"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="7"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="8"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="9"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="0"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="Delete"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_enter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="Enter"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</merge>
```

PLease help to randomize the position of number button like the image

Comment: why randomize the position of the keypad? just randomize the value inside each button. that way your layout will be intact and you can just get the text value from the clicked button

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to make use of the default keyboard, looking at the documentation and at the different Keyboard Types [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType#TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL), there are six different keyboard types that likely relate to your use case:

- TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL
- TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED
- TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_NORMAL
- TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD
- TYPE_CLASS_PHONE
- TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER

There are many other keyboard types you can use, some which include numbers, but these are the main ones you should consider.

For what you want to do, it's not really possible with the default Android keyboard as far as I know. This leaves you with two options. The first would be to use one of the input types above which can be applied to an EditText by doing either:

```
editTextName.setRawInputType(TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD) // In code

android:inputType="numberPassword" // In xml
```

The other option you have that I have seen on some banking apps is that it asks not for the full pin, but only part of the pin. They may ask for digits 4, 2 and 1, just using the normal keyboard. This would create some complexity which you may be looking for. The example shown in the picture below is from a website, but you could create the same thing easily on Android.

[image]

Hope this helps and good luck.